# testcafe Expect click to fail

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

Is it possible to expect a click to fail with testcafe?

I'm using testcafe studio.

After I hit a submit button on my page, I want a test to make sure that some text is no longer on the page.

What is the best way of doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found one way of ensuring that the element wasn't on the page:

[image]

I used a `t.notOk(Selector(mySelectorHere).count)`

Answer (score 2):

In your test scenario you can use [`exists`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#check-if-an-element-exists) `Selector` property:

```
Selector('h1').withText('Some text').exists
```